# UIImage layer mask is offsetting image

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage

I have the following code that is intended to round just the bottom corners of a UIImage via a layer mask. The code works fine as far as rounding the corners go, but when I do so, it is creating a strange offset and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Here it is, without the code (Notice how it lines up on the bottom with the purple rounded rectangle sitting behind it):

[image]

And here it is with the layer mask code:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
//This section sets the corner radius & shadow of the purple rectangle.
totalTankRep.layer.cornerRadius = 8
totalTankRep.clipsToBounds = true
totalTankRep.layer.masksToBounds = false;
totalTankRep.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0);
totalTankRep.layer.shadowRadius = 8;
totalTankRep.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;


//This defaults the green rectangle to 0 (for the top corners)
oilLevelRep.layer.cornerRadius = 0


//This applies a layer mask that rounds the corners
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: oilLevelRep.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 0.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
oilLevelRep.layer.mask = maskLayer
view.addSubview(oilLevelRep)
```

Any idea what's going on here, and how I can fix this?

Comment: can you try increasing oilLevelRep.bounds height when creating the UIBezierPath? It look like Mask is reducing the height of green rectangle